# Reposting an interesting but crappy question as one's own

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, bad-questions

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412748) which was interesting¹ but pretty poorly presented. If you take a look, make sure to view the original rather than the one that has benefited from at least one non-OP edit and note that enough tech-tags were added to nominate this for the 'throw-crap-at-a-wall-to-see-what-sticks' award.

I created an answer but left it as a draft. I left a comment as a nudge for the OP to improve the question with [some original effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) but alas no improvement(s) to the original question came from the OP and the question has so far received four close votes and seems abandoned.

As I am left with my draft response I've cleaned up the question and reposted it as [my own question²](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414210) complete with my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414210/if-a-cell-starts-with-a-specific-text-how-do-i-replicate-the-value-of-that-cell/48414211#48414211) from my original draft. For kicks and giggles, I plan to leave it for a few days then post a bounty and award it to the best solution to the second part of the question.

Is this an appropriate re-purposing or recycling of bad questions? Should I mark the original question as a duplicate of my own?

¹ <sub>Yeah I know this particular question has been asked and answered at least a dozen times but TBH I can rewrite the question and provide an answer in less time than it takes to find a duplicate using stackoverflow's search engine.</sub>

² <sub>Yeah I know that even my revised question asks **two** specific questions (*if starts with* and *if contains*) but they are very closely related and the important part of the solution is common to both.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

This feels ***incredibly*** scummy.  The scummy circle completes itself if you mark *yours* as a duplicate of *theirs* even though *you* plagiarized **three-fourths of *their* question**.

I'm not really sure what you're waiting on.  The OP isn't likely going to provide any prior work.  They probably don't know what a filter even *is*.  **Just post your answer.**

What are you trying to prove by reposting their ***exact*** question with a little effort slapped in for the theater of it?  Why would you even *bother* with the ceremony at that point?  It's *literally* serving no purpose for this question.

The OP *didn't* come to Stack Overflow with a neat little bundle of code that we can tinker and point out their errors.  They asked for an approach.  You have two options:  either provide them with that help or don't.  If your major gripe is with the fact that their post lacks an MCVE, I fear that the moniker has done far too much damage to the community already.

Comment: re: *'What are you trying to prove ...'* Actually i'm not trying to prove anything. Merely trying to improve the quality of questions left un-roomba'ed. I'm good with leaving or deleting my effort after taking the temperature of my actions here in meta.

Comment: @Jeeped:  The main thing that this question needed was an edit.  Nothing more, nothing less.  The OP isn't going to have this question magically fit our mold if they provide prior work.  I get that your efforts were done with good intentions, but you're *way* overcomplicating things.

Comment: I don't edit questions to include content that should have been included to begin with. However, it seems that your response is in keeping with the prevalent SO attitude in this matter. I'll wait another hour or so and then likely delete my effort.

Comment: @Jeeped:  Oh no, don't misinterpret me there.  I'm not saying you should've edited in the MCVE.  I'm saying that there were other grammar and sentence flow things that could've been improved instead.

Comment: While I find your prevalent use of the adjective/adverb **scummy** a little distasteful, your response seems to reflect the overwhelming attitude of the meta participants in my misguided endeavor.

Answer (score 10):

You've plagiarised someone else's content, period. Disregarding everything else, that should be enough for you to realize what you're doing isn't right.

Even if we look past the plagiarism, you've deliberately posted a question which is a duplicate of the original question. A question you yourself admit is a duplicate of others. Adding in a small 'what I've tried' section is not sufficient to differentiate the questions.

So, I really fail to see how there's *any* benefit in what you've done.

Comment: Not to mention... a duplicate, "crappy" question. Isn't quality content our number 1 goal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ok to post your interpretation of unclear or too broad question as new question with or without an answer. Use your own judgement if you believe they should become duplicates - posting "canonical" version of the question may be ok.

Note that editing original question may change meaning and thus not a good idea.

**On the particular linked question:** that question is neither "unclear" nor "too broad" but simply "zero-effort" post. Whether we want to encourage such questions or close them in some way is separate question, but I'd not re-post it with some fake research. If you know that it is duplicate - close as such (there are other search engines beyond SO to find duplicate) or provide an answer (and possibly do minor edits to question).

Comment: Alexei...the OP actually copied the "zero-effort" post verbatim.  I really don't feel that a generic response is warranted here.

Comment: @Makoto good point. I'll keep generic answer here if OP decides to generalize the question. In mean time I've added attribution to that new question to align with SO policy.